# Using an Inner Join as a Query criteria on a Union Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have table that tracks employee QA data. It tracks the Employee (UserLogin) the Date of the Employee work (NoteDate) and 5 yes/no fields (as well as other unrelated fields for the purposes of this query and more trends that match the following code). A separate table tracks the Employee Data including the unit(Unit) they are on. I have a Union Query that is drawing out the fields I noted for the purpose of creating a crosstab that summarizes the accuracy percentage. I now want to be able to use the same queries to track just one teams performance. I have tried doing an inner join to the employee table using the UserLogin field that appears in both as the join.  I'm then asking the query to use the team I specify in a control to query only those team members and summarize their data. Here is the first query that works great for all employees.

```
SELECT            ID AS SourceID
                , UserLogin
                , Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr
                , Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo
                , "Appeal" AS Trend 
FROM              tblQA 
WHERE             Appeal=False

UNION SELECT      ID
                , UserLogin
                , Year([NoteDate])
                , Format([NoteDate], "mmm")
                , "NRP" 
FROM tblQA 
WHERE             NRP = False

UNION SELECT      ID
                , UserLogin
                , Year([NoteDate])
                , Format([NoteDate], "mmm")
                , "ChurnEscalation" 
FROM              tblQA 
WHERE             ChurnEscalation = False

UNION SELECT      ID
                , UserLogin
                , Year([NoteDate])
                , Format([NoteDate], "mmm")
                , "ProtocolNotFollowed" 
FROM              tblQA 
WHERE             ProtocolNotFollowed = False

UNION SELECT      ID
                , UserLogin
                , Year([NoteDate])
                , Format([NoteDate], "mmm")
                , "Resubmission" 
FROM              tblQA 
WHERE             Resubmission = False
```

And then the first few lines of my attempt at the new code here.

```
SELECT tblQA.ID AS SourceID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Appeal" AS Trend FROM tblQA  INNER JOIN tblUser ON tblQA.UserLogin = tblUser.UserLogin WHERE Appeal=FALSE AND (((tblUser.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT]))
UNION SELECT tblQA.ID AS SourceID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "NRP" AS Trend FROM tblQA  INNER JOIN tblUser ON tblQA.UserLogin = tblUser.UserLogin WHERE Appeal=FALSE AND (((tblUser.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT]))
UNION SELECT tblQA.ID AS SourceID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "ChurnEscalation" AS Trend FROM tblQA  INNER JOIN tblUser ON tblQA.UserLogin = tblUser.UserLogin WHERE Appeal=FALSE AND (((tblUser.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT]))
UNION SELECT tblQA.ID AS SourceID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "ProtocolNotFollowed" AS Trend FROM tblQA  INNER JOIN tblUser ON tblQA.UserLogin = tblUser.UserLogin WHERE Appeal=FALSE AND (((tblUser.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT]))
UNION SELECT tblQA.ID AS SourceID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Resubmission" AS Trend FROM tblQA  INNER JOIN tblUser ON tblQA.UserLogin = tblUser.UserLogin WHERE Appeal=FALSE AND (((tblUser.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT]))
```

I'm not getting results that appear valid though - 700% accuracy on trends and all trends the same value. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

[Here is an image of the results I get with all items tracked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1cST.jpg)
Edit- Ok I made some progress but am still having some trouble.  I realized in a followup query (the one based on June7's DataUNION code) I was drawing my total QA count from all staff not just the unit so I changed that code to add the unit criteria.

```
SELECT    DataUNIONUnitAD.Yr
        , DataUNIONUnitAD.Mo
        , DataUNIONUnitAD.Trend
        , Count(DataUNIONUnitAD.UserLogin) AS CountOfUserLogin
        , ctqADUnitTrends.CntYrMo
        , Count([UserLogin])/[CntYrMo]*100 AS Pct 
FROM    (
         SELECT       Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr
                    , Format([NoteDate],"mmm") AS Mo
                    , Count(tblQA.ID) AS CntYrMo 
         FROM         tblQA 
         WHERE        (((tblUser.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT])) 
         GROUP BY     Year([NoteDate])
                    , Format([NoteDate],"mmm")
        ) AS ctqADUnitTrends INNER JOIN DataUNIONUnitAD ON 
            (ctqADUnitTrends.Mo = DataUNIONUnitAD.Mo) AND (ctqADUnitTrends.Yr = DataUNIONUnitAD.Yr) 
GROUP BY  DataUNIONUnitAD.Yr
        , DataUNIONUnitAD.Mo
        , DataUNIONUnitAD.Trend
        , ctqADUnitTrends.CntYrMo;
```

That gives me The right order of magnitude percentages, but all trends are still the same. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yIzi.jpg) I've tried to look to see if I can identify where I may have inadvertently changed something but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Provide sample data. The crosstab actually runs, shows odd results?

Comment: Hello June7! I was hoping you'd see this. Your code is working great and I've been trying to expand on it. I was also thinking I might try just creating a 4th query that runs first that just selects the relevant QA's and then point this query at that. Thank you again for looking at it!

Comment: I tested the UNION with join and filter criteria. The CROSSTAB output looks fine, at least with the data I built.

Comment: Thank you again for helping with this June7! Are you placing the AND (filter) on every UNION SELECT line when you do it?

Comment: Yes, that would be required.

Comment: June7: That's what I did. I'm not getting why all of the data points collected with the UNION SELECT are coming back with the same average value by month. Its like its averaging all of the different fields into one total average for each month. I tried running just the DataUnion query and it returned zero results which is even more baffling. How can I be getting averages on the subsequent queries when the base results are zero?

Comment: I'm trying out June7 s solution below now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, don't change the UNION query, adjust the subsequent queries (BTW, note changes in query names):

The UNION query:
`SELECT ID AS SourceID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Appeal" AS Trend FROM tblQA WHERE Appeal=True
UNION SELECT ID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "NRP" FROM tblQA WHERE NRP=True
UNION SELECT ID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Churn" FROM tblQA WHERE ChurnEscalation=True
UNION SELECT ID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Protocol" FROM tblQA WHERE ProtocolNotFollowed=True
UNION SELECT ID, tblQA.UserLogin, Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Resub" FROM tblQA WHERE Resubmission=True;`

The aggregate query:
`SELECT QA_UNION.Yr, QA_UNION.Mo, QA_UNION.Trend, QA_UNION.UserLogin, tblUser.Unit, Query3.CntYrMo, Count(*) AS CountOfUser, Count(*)/[CntYrMo]*100 AS Pct
FROM tblUser INNER JOIN ((SELECT Year([NoteDate]) AS Yr, Format([NoteDate],"mmm") AS Mo, Count([tblQA].ID) AS CntYrMo FROM tblQA GROUP BY Year([NoteDate]), Format([NoteDate],"mmm"))  AS Query3 INNER JOIN QA_UNION ON (Query3.Mo = QA_UNION.Mo) AND (Query3.Yr = QA_UNION.Yr)) ON tblUser.UserLogin = QA_UNION.UserLogin
GROUP BY QA_UNION.Yr, QA_UNION.Mo, QA_UNION.Trend, QA_UNION.UserLogin, tblUser.Unit, Query3.CntYrMo;`

Then the CROSSTAB:
`PARAMETERS [Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM First(QA_COUNT.Pct) AS FirstOfPct
SELECT QA_COUNT.Yr, QA_COUNT.Trend, QA_COUNT.Unit
FROM QA_COUNT
WHERE (((QA_COUNT.Unit)=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![txtADUnitPT]))
GROUP BY QA_COUNT.Yr, QA_COUNT.Trend, QA_COUNT.Unit
PIVOT QA_COUNT.Mo In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");`

Comment: I'm getting a "This expression is typed incorrectly, or is complex to be evaluated." message. I'm sorry to have to keep asking questions June7, I did a direct copy/paste of your code, using the original working dataUNION and renaming it QA_UNION.

Comment: I am running the 3 queries with sample dataset and no error. You renamed the aggregate query to QA_COUNT as referenced in the CROSSTAB?

Comment: I did, I just copied your text into a new query and named it QA_COUNT. could you maybe post the code for your Aggregate query as well just to make sure I didnt screw something up?

Comment: That is the aggregate query in my answer. Did you mean the UNION? Edited answer.

Comment: Wait, I am still using True in criteria. Will have to revise and test further. Done. Still works.

Comment: Is there a limit to how much data Access can process? I've copied your code directly and not changed any names, and I've verfied that youre using the same field names I am, etc. I keep getting the "This expression is typed incorrectly, or is complex..." message when I try to run query3 however. Right now there are about 5k records and I'm wondering if I need to be searching a smaller time period or something.

Comment: 5k is not a lot but wouldn't hurt to test with smaller set. I created only 6 records for testing. Perhaps the PARAMETER is not working right. Try a static criteria or an input popup (which is what I use in my test).

Comment: Also, though has no bearing on the error, maybe UserLogin should be removed from the QA_COUNT grouping.